# Verificar la existencia de un correo electronico en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poder verificar si un correo electrónico es real. Ya utilicé el SMTPCLIENT de C# para enviar un correo electrónico, pero no me dice al momento si el correo es válido o no.

La Idea es como simular un correo, pero que la respuesta sea inmediata.

Estoy desarrollando en ASP.NET C#.

Quisiera saber que procedimiento puedo usar. Espero puedan ayudarme,Gracias

Comment: Desafortunadamente no hay forma hasta que se envía el correo, después el servidor determinará si el correo pudo ser entregado o no a los destinatarios

Comment: bueno hasta donde se eso no es posible lo unico que podrias hacer es que el mail es un mail que cuenta con un @ y un dominio como gmail.com ,pero lo que comentas creo que no eas posible.

Comment: No puedes saberlo. SMTPClient entrega el correo al servidor SMTP pero no puede saber si el correo ha llegado al destinatario.

Comment: Si, bueno el formato del correo ya lo valido, pero solo queria saber si el correo es real y existe en el servidor, algo como esta aplicación http://verify-email.org/

Comment: **Hola Ernesto, pudiste encontrar la solución?** Hoy me encuentro con este mismo caso, necesito saber si el correo llegó y enviar un mensaje al usuario que su correo no fue enviado que verifique el **correo** que ingreso e intente mas tarde. Agregue un Catch y nada!!! catch (System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException ex) { throw ex; } Si encontraste la solución, te agradeceria que me la compartas, respondiendo a tu misma pregunta, Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola Assiel, disculpa pero temo decirte que no encontré una solucion a este problema, quizas el lenguaje no es capaz, me temo que no puedo ayudarte, una disculpa y buena suerte espero tu si encuentres la solucion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe esa funcionalidad bajo el protocolo `SMTP`, lo mas aproximado que podrias lograr es enviar un mail en donde la persona ingrese a un link para verificar que le llego correctamente, pero sera una operacion manual.

Es lo mismo que se implementa cuanto te registra en un sitio, el cual envia un mail el cual al navegarlo confirma el registro.

No es una limitacion del lenguaje, simplemente el protocolo de mail no soporta esto que buscas implementar.

---

Sino una alternativa podria ser:

[Check if Email Address Really Exist or not Using C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kirtan007/check-if-email-address-really-exist-or-not-using-C-Sharp/)

pero aqui estarias ejecutando comando socket contra el servicio de smtp para ver si responde con la existencia del mail, no lo he probado, pero podria ser una opcion.

Comment: Muchas gracias por laexplicacion, ahoraya me queda mas clara :)